# Fixed table headings not aligning with columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you choose Tier 2, 3, or 5 another table displays but the headings don't line up with the columns.  It worked at one time.  If I change the html on line 27 to style="display: block;" it starts off looking okay, but once you make a selection it goes out of whack.

I tried to add a jsfiddle link and it didn't take it.

```js
function show_hide_choices() {

  var lTier = parseInt(document.getElementById('tier').value);

  //alert('show_hide_dependents: lTier = ' + lTier);

  if (lTier == 1) // Won (no lines)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 1.  This line will never show.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineA").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineB").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineC").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineD").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lTier == 2) // Too (one line)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 2.  Please fill in the information below.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineA").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineB").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineC").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineD").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lTier == 3) // Three (two lines)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 3.  Please fill in the information below.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineA").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineB").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineC").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineD").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lTier == 4) // Shouldn't be a valid response
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 4.  This line will never show.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineA").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineB").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineC").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("lineD").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lTier == 5) // Five (Four lines)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 5.  Please fill in the information below.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineA").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineB").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineC").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("lineD").style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```css
div.depPhrase {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
}

table.moreThan1 {
  width: 75%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

col.column1 {
  width: 6.5%;
}

col.column2 {
  width: 14.5%;
}

col.column3 {
  width: 6%;
}

tr.lineA,
tr.lineB,
tr.lineC,
tr.lineD {
  display: block;
}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="tier">
        Choose Tier:
       </label>
    </th>
    <th class="required">*</th>
    <td>
      <select name="tier" id="tier" tabindex="120" size="4" onchange="show_hide_choices();">
        <option value='1' selected="selected">1 - Won</option>
        <option value='2'>2 - Too</option>
        <option value='3'>3 - Three</option>
        <option value='5'>5 - Five</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>


<div class="depPhrase" id="depPhrase" style="display: none;">
  You have chosen ----. Please fill in the information below.
</div>


<table id="moreThan1" class="moreThan1" style="display: block;">

  <colgroup>
    <col class="column1">
    <col class="column2">
    <col class="column3">
  </colgroup>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column1">First</th>
      <th class="column2">Second</th>
      <th class="column3">Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="column1">Col Hdg</th>
      <th class="column2">Col Hdg</th>
      <th class="column3">Col Hdg</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="lineA">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipA" id="relationship" tabindex="820">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameA" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="840" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberA" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="860" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lineB">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipB" id="relationship" tabindex="960">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameB" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="980" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberB" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="1000" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lineC">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipC" id="relationship" tabindex="1100">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameC" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="1120" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberC" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="1140" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lineD">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipD" id="relationship" tabindex="1240">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameD" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="1260" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberD" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="1280" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Without any code to look at it will be difficult to help with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default display value for a `<tr>` is `table-row`. Even you don't know the initial value, you can set to empty string. The browser will fallback for you.

Furthermore, the if branch can be shorten using css class. Check the bottom of the css.

```js
function show_hide_choices() {

  var lTier = parseInt(document.getElementById('tier').value);

  //alert('show_hide_dependents: lTier = ' + lTier);

  // control line display with css class
  document.querySelectorAll('.line').forEach(function(e) {
    e.classList.remove('line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5');
    e.classList.add(`line${lTier}`);
  });

  if (lTier == 1) // Won (no lines)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 1.  This line will never show.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lTier == 2) // Too (one line)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 2.  Please fill in the information below.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'block';
  } else if (lTier == 3) // Three (two lines)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 3.  Please fill in the information below.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'block';
  } else if (lTier == 4) // Shouldn't be a valid response
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 4.  This line will never show.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (lTier == 5) // Five (Four lines)
  {
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").innerHTML = 'You have chosen 5.  Please fill in the information below.';
    document.getElementById("depPhrase").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("moreThan1").style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```css
div.depPhrase {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 0% 1% 0%;
}

table.moreThan1 {
  width: 75%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

col.column1 {
  width: 6.5%;
}

col.column2 {
  width: 14.5%;
}

col.column3 {
  width: 6%;
}

tr.lineA,
tr.lineB,
tr.lineC,
tr.lineD {
  display: block;
}

.column1,
.column2,
.column3 {
  text-align: left;
}


/* control line display with css class */

#lineA.line1,
#lineB.line1,
#lineC.line1,
#lineD.line1 {
  display: none;
}

#lineB.line2,
#lineC.line2,
#lineD.line2 {
  display: none;
}

#lineC.line3,
#lineD.line3 {
  display: none;
}

#lineA.line4,
#lineB.line4,
#lineC.line4,
#lineD.line4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="tier">
        Choose Tier:
       </label>
    </th>
    <th class="required">*</th>
    <td>
      <select name="tier" id="tier" tabindex="120" size="4" onchange="show_hide_choices();">
        <option value='1' selected="selected">1 - Won</option>
        <option value='2'>2 - Too</option>
        <option value='3'>3 - Three</option>
        <option value='5'>5 - Five</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>


<div class="depPhrase" id="depPhrase" style="display: none;">
  You have chosen ----. Please fill in the information below.
</div>


<table id="moreThan1" class="moreThan1" style="display: block;">

  <colgroup>
    <col class="column1">
    <col class="column2">
    <col class="column3">
  </colgroup>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column1">First</th>
      <th class="column2">Second</th>
      <th class="column3">Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="column1">Col Hdg</th>
      <th class="column2">Col Hdg</th>
      <th class="column3">Col Hdg</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="lineA" class="line">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipA" id="relationship" tabindex="820">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameA" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="840" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberA" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="860" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lineB" class="line">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipB" id="relationship" tabindex="960">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameB" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="980" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberB" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="1000" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lineC" class="line">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipC" id="relationship" tabindex="1100">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameC" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="1120" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberC" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="1140" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lineD" class="line">
      <td class="column1">
        <select name="relationshipD" id="relationship" tabindex="1240">
          <option value="">Select One</option>
          <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="Child">Child/Step-Child</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <input name="fullNameD" type="text" id="fullName" maxlength="50" size="40" tabindex="1260" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="column3">
        <input name="identNumberD" type="text" id="identNumber" maxlength="11" size="11" tabindex="1280" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think your snippet can be further refactor using the same approach on `depPhrase` and `moreThan1`